# lxml.etree ImportError on python 2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, lxml

I tried to switch to python 2.7.10 but failed on trying to import lxml.etree.

I made small edits to [this guide](http://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-ubuntu-and-linuxmint/) in order to install python 2.7.10

```
./configure --prefix /usr/local/lib/python-2.7.10
make
make install
```

After that I made virtualenv based on this python folder

```
mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/local/lib/python-2.7.10/bin/python Py2710VirtEnv
```

Installed all the necessary lxml prerequisites and lxml itself

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev
CFLAGS="-O0" pip install lxml
```

When I start python under Py2710VirtEnv I get the right version number (Python 2.7.10).

`import lxml` also works fine.

But when I type `from lxml import etree` I get an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "stdin", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: /root/Envs/Py2710VirtEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: PyFPE_jbuf

I looked over a couple of question about lxml.etree ImportError but I didn't find the suitable answer. Everything works perfectly well on virtualenv with py 2.7.6

So I have two major questions:

1. (obvious) about the error itself
2. (general) is it a right way to install and use python 2.7.10 with virtualenv?

Comment: Importing lxml and then calling lxml.etree doesn't work, right?